# UDP packets from kernel

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, linux-kernel

I would like to know what is this and how can i stop this?

```
Apr 10 15:30:17 -- kernel: [ 1182.295900] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:16:3e:5b:f3:c1:00:08:e3:ff:fd:90:08:00 SRC=95.37.189.176 DST=109.123.***.*** LEN=159 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=114 ID=29111 PROTO=UDP SPT=49001 DPT=51413 LEN=139 
Apr 10 15:30:37 -- kernel: [ 1202.267330] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:16:3e:5b:f3:c1:00:08:e3:ff:fd:90:08:00 SRC=95.37.189.176 DST=109.123.***.*** LEN=159 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=114 ID=29416 PROTO=UDP SPT=49001 DPT=51413 LEN=139 
Apr 10 15:30:52 -- kernel: [ 1217.281373] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:16:3e:5b:f3:c1:00:08:e3:ff:fd:90:08:00 SRC=95.37.189.176 DST=109.123.***.*** LEN=159 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=114 ID=29671 PROTO=UDP SPT=49001 DPT=51413 LEN=139 
Apr 10 15:31:12 -- kernel: [ 1237.328931] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:16:3e:5b:f3:c1:00:08:e3:ff:fd:90:08:00 SRC=95.37.189.176 DST=109.123.***.*** LEN=159 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=114 ID=30023 PROTO=UDP SPT=49001 DPT=51413 LEN=139 
Apr 10 15:31:32 -- kernel: [ 1257.315439] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:16:3e:5b:f3:c1:00:08:e3:ff:fd:90:08:00 SRC=95.37.189.176 DST=109.123.***.*** LEN=159 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=114 ID=30696 PROTO=UDP SPT=49001 DPT=51413 LEN=139 
Apr 10 15:32:05 -- kernel: [ 1290.234491] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:16:3e:5b:f3:c1:00:08:e3:ff:fd:90:08:00 SRC=84.109.202.82 DST=109.123.***.*** LEN=131 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=119 ID=31832 PROTO=UDP SPT=40310 DPT=51413 LEN=111 
Apr 10 15:32:23 -- kernel: [ 1307.980102] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:16:3e:5b:f3:c1:00:08:e3:ff:fd:90:08:00 SRC=83.173.164.230 DST=109.123.***.*** LEN=90 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=118 ID=11943 PROTO=UDP SPT=7614 DPT=51413 LEN=70 
Apr 10 15:32:43 -- kernel: [ 1328.282917] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:16:3e:5b:f3:c1:00:08:e3:ff:fd:90:08:00 SRC=95.37.189.176 DST=109.123.***.*** LEN=159 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=114 ID=498 PROTO=UDP SPT=49001 DPT=51413 LEN=139 
Apr 10 15:33:07 -- kernel: [ 1352.057985] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:16:3e:5b:f3:c1:00:08:e3:ff:fd:90:08:00 SRC=178.65.17.253 DST=109.123.***.*** LEN=93 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=114 ID=12980 PROTO=UDP SPT=17161 DPT=51413 LEN=73 
Apr 10 15:33:27 -- kernel: [ 1371.704693] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:16:3e:5b:f3:c1:00:08:e3:ff:fd:90:08:00 SRC=219.92.149.107 DST=109.123.***.*** LEN=90 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=116 ID=29322 PROTO=UDP SPT=17830 DPT=51413 LEN=70 
Apr 10 15:34:00 -- kernel: [ 1405.283656] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:16:3e:5b:f3:c1:00:08:e3:ff:fd:90:08:00 SRC=88.163.201.210 DST=109.123.***.*** LEN=86 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=34 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=51413 DPT=51413 LEN=66 
Apr 10 15:34:24 -- kernel: [ 1429.056082] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:16:3e:5b:f3:c1:00:08:e3:ff:fd:90:08:00 SRC=79.161.107.135 DST=109.123.***.*** LEN=86 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=54 ID=11650 PROTO=UDP SPT=51413 DPT=51413 LEN=66 
Apr 10 15:34:44 -- kernel: [ 1448.519678] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:16:3e:5b:f3:c1:00:08:e3:ff:fd:90:08:00 SRC=79.97.126.17 DST=109.123.***.*** LEN=90 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=118 ID=14779 PROTO=UDP SPT=8994 DPT=51413 LEN=70 
Apr 10 15:34:46 -- kernel: [ 1450.537619] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:16:3e:5b:f3:c1:00:08:e3:ff:fd:90:08:00 SRC=89.228.5.234 DST=109.123.***.*** LEN=90 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=111 ID=24500 PROTO=UDP SPT=26726 DPT=51413 LEN=70 
Apr 10 15:35:10 -- kernel: [ 1475.386314] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:16:3e:5b:f3:c1:00:08:e3:ff:fd:90:08:00 SRC=84.194.210.246 DST=109.123.***.*** LEN=90 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=119 ID=28236 PROTO=UDP SPT=15826 DPT=51413 LEN=70 
Apr 10 15:35:20 -- kernel: [ 1485.110655] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:16:3e:5b:f3:c1:00:08:e3:ff:fd:90:08:00 SRC=217.132.83.138 DST=109.123.***.*** LEN=126 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x20 TTL=118 ID=15848 PROTO=UDP SPT=21629 DPT=51413 LEN=106
```

Answer (score 2):

Caused by the user mode firewall. You have a service running on port `51413`?

You can determine the service that's running against this port using:

```
sudo netstat -lp | grep 51413
```

bittorrent client?

You can disable the logging using:

```
sudo ufw logging off
```

If you want to enable the port, I think the command you need to use is:

```
sudo ufw allow in 51413
```